# Pandas - link an aggregated row back to its original elements

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation, linkage

I would like to perform an aggregation on some data , but once done, link the aggregate back to the rows which made up the aggregate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"vehicle":  ['car','bus','bus' ,'car','bus'],
               "colour" :  ['red','red','blue','red','blue'],
               "weight" :  [ 1,    14,   10,    2,    12]
            })

grouped = df.groupby(["vehicle", "colour"], as_index=False)
print grouped.agg({"weight":"sum"})

vehicle colour  weight
0     bus   blue      22
1     bus    red      14
2     car    red       3
```

Say I want to display the aggregates, I can iterate through the above aggregate data.
However, I also want to be able to determine / display the rows which made up any given aggregate. I.e. I need to be able to efficiently determine that the red car aggregate, is comprised of row 0 and row 3 in the original data set

Ultimately I'd like to persist this relationship to a file - but I'm unsure if this could be accomplished in one combined dataset, or if I'd need two separate data sets - with a way of linking any given aggregate back to the rows in the original data

My main question is - how do I determine the red car = 3, is comprised of rows 0 and 3 in the original dataset.

Many thanks for any help,
Marcus

Comment: This would be easier to understand with a toy example. Also you should link to the previous question, it's unclear exactly what's different here (are you looking to transform rather than agg)?

Comment: Can you illustrate (either with a toy example or some sort of simple diagram) what you mean by "link"?

Comment: @marcusadamski please edit your question with that, it's better suited for updates like this (with formatting etc.) :)

Comment: @Andy Hayden - had trouble describing my changes in the comment, so as suggested, updated my original question.

Comment: @marcusadamski I think I see what you're asking (thanks for editing)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index) operation between your original dataframe and the resulting aggregated data:

```
key_cols = ["Date", "TextA", "TextB"]
grouped = data.groupby(key_cols)
data.join(grouped.agg({"NumberA":"sum", "NumberB": "min"}), on=key_cols, rsuffix='_agg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groups dictionary:

```
In [11]: grouped.groups[('car', 'red')]
Out[11]: [0, 3]

In [12]: df.loc[grouped.groups[('car', 'red')]]
Out[12]:
  colour vehicle  weight
0    red     car       1
3    red     car       2
```

You have to be a bit careful, as in general this returns the *labels* (and not the integer locations).
Because it uses labels this solution fails with repeat indexes, so it may be a better idea to use the indices dictionary (which uses the integer location):

```
In [21]: df.index = list('abcdd')
```

See that the above solution fails (due to the repeat in the index):

```
In [22]: grouped.groups[('car', 'red')]
Out[22]: ['a', 'd']

In [23]: df.loc[grouped.groups[('car', 'red')]]
Out[23]:
  colour vehicle  weight
a    red     car       1
d    red     car       2
d   blue     bus      12
```

But with indices (integer location) it works fine:

```
In [24]: grouped.indices[('car', 'red')]
Out[24]: array([0, 3])

In [25]: df.iloc[grouped.indices[('car', 'red')]]
Out[25]:
  colour vehicle  weight
a    red     car       1
d    red     car       2
```